# Pointermove does not fire for touch on IE

Tags: javascript

I want to listen to `pointermove` event on IE11, but it seems that `pointermove` only fires for mouse (and possibly pen), but not when you are using your finger.

http://jsfiddle.net/qq2hjL2g/

Actually, the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn304886(v=vs.85).aspx) says that it fires for pens/mice, so this may not be really a bug.

But, is there any way to listen to pointermove on IE for touch? There must be, but I was very surprised to see `pointermove` not firing at all.

**EDIT:** I found that if I put CSS `touch-action: none` on the div, pointermove events fire. But why? I'm trying to find documents related to this, but I couldn't find any so far.

**EDIT:** I learend that the `touch-action` CSS specifies which touch actions are handled by the browser. This means setting `touch-action` to `none` tells the browser to *not* handle any touch events, and the developer is responsible for controlling the behaviour throutgh JavaScript events. This is why I was getting the events fired properly only when I had the CSS. (See more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action).)

Comment: Thanks for your edits.  This really saved me.  In our app, for whatever reason, in IE11 the onmousemove was firing before onmousedown in our signature box, which blew everything up of course.  Using that touch-action: none and then using onpointerdown and onpointermove worked.  THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also trying to interface with IE11 touch.
I believe MSGesture is used for touch events because in their documentation they refer to "fingers"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465856.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/hh968249.aspx

I believe the gestures you are interested in are:
MSGestureStart - "Triggered when the screen is touched on a location over this element."

MSGestureChange - "Triggered when the finger positions associated with the interaction moves on the screen."

MSGestureEnd - "This event fires when all associated contacts are removed from the surface"

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but it looks promising. Thank you.